# Why do you need to assign class to variable to use it? Unlike function

Tags: python, function, class

I am just learning, and have a confusion
In this code I assign  dice=Dice().. Why not just use Dice.roll()?? It yells at me about positional arguments ;(
Could you please clarify a difference, why do I need that in comparison to functions?

```
import random
class Dice:
    def roll(self):
        a=random.randint(1,6)
        b = random.randint(1, 6)
        return a,b


dice=Dice()
print(dice.roll())
```

Comment: You should reread on object oriented programming. `dice = Dice()` creates a new `Dice` **object** and assigns it to the `dice` variable. Likewise you could create another dice like so: `dice2 = Dice()`. Now you have two `Dice` objects but only one `Dice` class. This is similar how you can have multiple dices laying on your table, yet they all exhibit the same common behaviours.

Comment: I recommend that you take a deeper look at some Python tutorial to learn more about classes. This example is not well chosen, as it does nothing more than what a function would do. SO is not an adequate place to replace tutorials.

Comment: Some keywords around the above are instance, class and static methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the `dice` function: it takes one argument, `self`. But when you call `Dice.roll()` you are passing zero arguments, hence the error.

When you do `dice.roll()` where `dice` is an *instance* of the `Dice` class, the first argument passed is automatically filled in with the `dice` object. A more explicit way to write it (overriding aside) would be `Dice.roll(dice)`.

This is not a good example of the use of classes, because there is no need for a `class` here to begin with. But imagine you wanted to have different kinds of dice, with different numbers of sides, it would be more useful:

```py
class Die:
    def __init__(self, sides):
        self.sides = sides
    def roll(self):
        return random.randint(1, self.sides)

die = Die(6)      # Create a 6-sided die.

print(die.roll()) # Roll our D6.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not assignment.

```
dice=Dice()
```

creates and initializes `dice` object as instance of `Dice` class.
Class is a template, a blueprint.
You should create an object, instance of that class in order to use it.